# HTML "First Time User" form best practice (Jade / Angular)

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, pug

So I'm trying to implement the following form in my app.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

This is a form which should appear the first time a user tries to create a task in our app. Now my question is, what is the best way to deal with something like this? I'm not a very good frontend-guy and this might be a trivial question, I'm sorry if it is - nevertheless, I don't know the answer to it.

I'm not that curious about components etc, those are ok but rather of the flow. How should the things be organized in the html/js. Do I create a separate button each time, should the elements be dynamically inserted somehow.. etc

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish the task you are describing here.  I may make a stab at making a suggestion on a direction for you; however, I fear that this question may be in danger of down votes / close votes due to it's lack of focus and missing code.  There doesn't seem to be a clear question.  Instead, it comes off as a plea for someone to push you in the right direction, which feels like you haven't tried to solve it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I want a direction not code snippets or the whole problem solved. Is asking for a direction that bad? Furthermore, your comment is completely unhelpful.

Comment: my comment is an attempt to help you to reword your question to make it less likely to be voted for closure.  I did, however, add an answer, as I stated I might.

Comment: remember that Stack Overflow is a knowledge repository, and it works the best when you can present a question where an answer very clearly addresses the issue, and the question itself is useful to others who may encounter the same issue in the future.  The more focused on the problem, the better.

Comment: I know, yet concepts are also subject to question and this concept of "step-by-step" form is not something I've seen discussed a lot..anywhere. I knew talented people with a lot more experience already encountered this and that's why I posted a more "general" question, and lo and behold, the talented people answered and pointed me into the (I would think) right direction. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use angular directives for this, dynamically showing them based on other values. This should get you in the right direction:

```
<label for="taskName">Task name:</label>
<input type="text" name="taskName"
       ng-model="task.name" />

<div ng-show="currentStep > 1">
    <label for="assigned">Assigned:</label>
    <select>
        <!-- options etc. -->
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-default"
            ng-click="nextStep()">{{ currentStep.nextText }}</button>
</div>
```

controller:

```
.controller("MyCtrl",
    ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.steps = [
            { number: 1, nextText: "Let's go!" },
            { number: 2, nextText: "Next, please" }
        ];

        $scope.task = {};

        $scope.currentIndex = 0;
        $scope.currentStep = $scope.steps[$scope.currentIndex];

        $scope.nextStep = function (){
            $scope.currentIndex += 1;
            $scope.currentStep = $scope.steps[$scope.currentIndex];
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about this direction

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a [built in directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch#!/) for this kind of process, `ngSwitch`.  Using it, you can define a series of steps, and change the display based on the value of the step you are on in the process.

```
<form ng-switch="wizardStep">
    <div ng-switch-when="Step1">This is Step 1</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="Step2">This is Step 2</div>
</form>
```